# How can I obtain the distinct values for a "|" delimited column?

Tags: r

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
+--+---------------------------+
|id|grids                      |
+--+---------------------------+
|c1|21257a|75589y|21257a|77589y|
|c2|21257a|21257a|21257a|21257a|
|c3|21257a|75589y|75589y|33421v|
```

However, since there are duplicate characters under the grids column, I'd like to extract only the distinct characters such that the dataframe becomes like this:

```
+--+---------------------------+
|id|grids                      |
+--+---------------------------+
|c1|21257a|75589y              |
|c2|21257a                     |
|c3|21257a|75589y|33421v       |
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Using `sapply` split the string on `|`, keep only `unique` value in each row and paste.

```
df$grids <- sapply(strsplit(df$grids, '|', fixed = TRUE), function(x) 
                   paste0(unique(x), collapse = '|'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a base R regex based approach:

```r
df$grids <- gsub("\\b(.+?)(?=\\|.*\\1)", "", df$grids, perl=TRUE)
df$grids <- gsub("^\\|+|\\|+$", "", df$grids)
df$grids <- gsub("\\|{2,}", "|", df$grids)
df

  id                grids
1 c1        21257a|75589y
2 c2               21257a
3 c3 21257a|75589y|33421v
```

**Data:**

```
df <- data.frame(id=c("c1", "c2", "c3"),
                 grids=c("21257a|75589y|21257a|75589y",
                         "21257a|21257a|21257a|21257a",
                         "21257a|75589y|75589y|33421v"))
```

For an explanation of the regex `\b(.+?)(?=\|.*\1)`, it matches any pipe-separated term for which we can find the same term *later* in the grid string.  If so, then we strip it by replacing with empty string.  There are also some cleanup steps to remove dangling multiple pipes which might be left behind (or at the beginning/end of the grid string).

Answer (score 0):

using [data](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67717231/2884859) by @Tim

```r
library(tidyverse)
df <- data.frame(id=c("c1", "c2", "c3"),
                 grids=c("21257a|75589y|21257a|75589y",
                         "21257a|21257a|21257a|21257a",
                         "21257a|75589y|75589y|33421v"))
df %>% mutate(grids = map_chr(str_split(grids, '\\|'), 
                              ~paste(unique(.x), collapse = '|')))
#>   id                  grids
#> 1 c1          21257a|75589y
#> 2 c2                 21257a
#> 3 c3   21257a|75589y|33421v
```

<sup>Created on 2021-05-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>